# what is implementation or execution Difference Between dictionary with keys as 0,1,2,.. and list in python

Tags: python, oop

```
li=[1,2]
dic={0:1,1:2}

print(li[0],dic[0])
```

> I have executed following code, they give the same result, is there
> any implementation or execution or difference in the way the list and
> dictionary are stored in memory.

it was mentioned on lectures that **Dictionary elements are directly accessed**, so list takes more time while accessing elements in a huge list compared to a dictionary with keys 0,1,2 with same data as in the list.

Any reasons or confirming hypothesis would be helpful.

> Thanks in advance, happy coding

Comment: What lectures? Both lists and dicts are essentially wrappers around arrays. The list index pretty much is the array index, while the dict index has to be hashed first.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Both operations are O(1) (constant), and list access will typically be slightly faster:

```
from timeit import timeit

L = [0 for i in range(10**8)]
D = {i:0 for i in range(10**8)}

%timeit L[9999999]
%timeit D[9999999]
```

Results:

```
35.6 ns ± 3.03 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
52.1 ns ± 2.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, cool. 
%timeit D[9999999],%timeit L[9999999] will also give the same result?

Comment: List access is faster as you have shown. I would like to add that a Dictionary allows to specify any index and does not require contiguous keys.